# How to pick dates in calendar using Flatpickr in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, flatpickr

I'm trying to add a date range calendar to a qualtrics survey, but I'm in way over my head.

**First**, I have zero knowledge on `JS training`, and `coding experience` aside from HTML, and playing in R for data management. Please, ELI5 (Explain Like I'm Five) on all of this, and be kind. I have a boss that has incredibly unrealistic expectations, and despite being told I have no coding experience, keeps expecting me to learn how to do everything. Rock & a hard place here.

Qualtrics is confusing because some of the code needs to be in the look & feel section, and some needs to be with the specific question.

**Second**, here's what I have so done far:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var inputId = 'QR~' + this.questionId;
var picker = (".selector").flatpickr(optional_config);
mode: "range",
minDate: new Date().fp_incr(14),
dateFormat: "n.j.y",
);
}
```

**What I want to achieve?** This is on my specific question. The goal is to have a calendar or a date entry box that requires you to select a date range, but none of the dates can be closer than 2 weeks from the current date.

I also want the dates to be written in `American style`, eg `4/6/18` or `12/11/19`, with no preceding zeros.

I believe what I have set up now will ask for a date range in a text entry box, and won't allow for any dates within two weeks from the current day.

> I've cobbled together what I can from these links:

[qualtricks add javascript link](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/question-options/add-javascript/)

[javascript and qualtrics getting started](https://medium.com/@mc_bloomfield/javascript-and-qualtrics-getting-started-34f113cbeaaa)

[javascript and qualtrics Best Practices](https://medium.com/@mc_bloomfield/javascript-qualtrics-c4bf4fb93fff)

[flatpickr getting started](https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/)

**So, my questions are:**

1. what I've done so far is valid?
2. What needs to be in the question specifically, and what needs to be in the "Look & Feel" part of Qualtrics?
3. **How do I make sure I don't undo the company header on the survey?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. No, what you've done is both logically and syntactically invalid.
2. Add the flatpickr library to the Look&Feel header in a `<script>` tag.  Your JavaScript code gets added to the date question.
3. If you add the flatpickr library in a `<script>` tag to what is already in the header it won't have any impact on the existing header.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pushing to get training paid for by my work, but they want to see that it's useful. It's a struggle, because I need to succeed without training to show that I need training, but I can't do too well (not that that's a risk right now) because then they'll think I don't need training. **sigh**